# Email DocuSign PDF with marked fields in PHP

Tags: docusignapi

I'm a beginner in DocuSign. I'm looking for an API in PHP which can be used to email a link which opens up the PDF in DocuSign with marked fields. I looked for many codes in Stackoverflow  and tried but it did not fulfill my need. It opened up the PDF without showing the marked fields and had to drag the fields each time. I want something similar to powerform where the fields in PDF are marked and can be emailed .
Its been many days I'm stuck on it but found no solution. Is it possible in PHP? Please help

Below is one of them I tried but it did not mark the fields
https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php

```
<?php
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, one document and send!
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$data = "{
  \"emailBlurb\":\"
                      Hi,
                        Thanks\",
  \"emailSubject\":\"Registering\",
  \"documents\":[
    {
      \"documentId\":\"1\",
      \"name\":\"".$document_name."\"
    }
  ],
  \"recipients\":{
    \"signers\":[
      {
        \"email\":\"$recipient_email\",
        \"name\":\"$name\",
        \"recipientId\":\"1\",
        \"tabs\":{
          \"signHereTabs\":[
            {
              \"anchorString\":\"Signature:\",
              \"anchorXOffset\":\"0\",
              \"anchorYOffset\":\"0\",
              \"documentId\":\"1\",
              \"pageNumber\":\"1\"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  \"status\":\"sent\"
}";  

$file_contents = file_get_contents($document_name);

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"REGISTRATION_FORM.pdf\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

// *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )
);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the signer is being asked to place fields during the signing ceremony is that there are no fields in the envelope assigned to the signer.

My guess is that the anchor text `Signature:` could not be found. Try looking for just the string `Signature`

But more importantly, I don't know where you found the example code, but it is not the way to go.

Instead, use the [Quickstart process](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) to obtain a working PHP program that uses the SDK, then modify it. Your code is attempting something much more difficult, creating the JSON in strings and using CURL.

Comment: Thanks. Quickstart helped